# Add a subdomain to all urls in Cakephp

Tags: cakephp, subdomain

I want all Cakephp urls to use a subdomain if it is present in the users session... so if there is an entry 'subdomain:user' in the session of the user all pages will have 'user' as a prefix: Eg user.example.com, user.example.com/settings.

Is there an easy way to do this?

thanks,

kSeudo

Comment: 2.0, have you any ideas?

Comment: Yes, but I'll have to answer in a couple hours, off to school

Comment: Cool, have fun and let me know if you think you have a solution :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are custom route classes you could use. Create a file in APP/Lib/Route called UserSubdomainRoute.php and put this in it.

```
<?php
App::uses('AuthComponent', 'Controller/Component');
class UserSubdomainRoute extends CakeRoute {

/**
 * @var CakeRequest
 */
    private $Request;

/**
 * Length of domain's TLD
 *
 * @var int
 */
    public static $_tldLength = 1;

    public function __construct($template, $defaults = array(), $options = array()) {
        parent::__construct($template, $defaults, $options);

        $this->Request = new CakeRequest();
        $this->options = array_merge(array('protocol' => 'http'), $options);
    }

/**
 * Sets tld length
 *
 * @param $length
 * @return mixed void|int
 */
    public static function tldLength($length = null) {
        if (is_null($length)) {
            return self::$_tldLength;
        }

        self::$_tldLength = $length;
    }

/**
 * Writes out full url with protocol and subdomain
 *
 * @param $params
 * @return string
 */
    protected function _writeUrl($params) {
        $protocol = $this->options['protocol'];
        $subdomain = AuthComponent::user('subdomain');
        if (empty($subdomain)) {
            $subdomain = 'www';
        }
        $domain = $this->_getDomain();
        $url = parent::_writeUrl($params);

        return "{$protocol}://{$subdomain}.{$domain}{$url}";
    }

/**
 * Get domain name
 *
 * @return string
 */
    protected function _getDomain() {
        return $this->Request->domain(self::$_tldLength);
    }

}
```

One improvement to the class would probably be to make the $Request static.

Unfortunately in Cake 2.0 there is no way to set a defaultRotueClass, however, I added that feature in 2.1+ and I don't want to tell you to upgrade so you are going to have to manually specify it for all your routes in the third param like so:

```
Router::connect(..., ..., array('routeClass' => 'UserSubdomainRoute');
```

Be sure to add at the top of routes.php

```
App::uses('UserSubdomainRoute', 'Lib/Route');
```

If you do upgrade to 2.1+ you can just add this at the top of your routes.php

```
Router::defaultRouteClass('UserSubdomainRoute');
```

Then any routs specified after will use that route class.

The main part of the route class is the `_writeUrl` method. It checks to see if there is a `subdomain` key set in the session otherwise uses `www` and builds the full url to return.

Heads Up: Haven't tested the class, still at school just wanted to give you a jump start. It's just a modifed version of my SubdomainRoute which works a bit differently (it used to only match routes to when a certain subdomain is set, for ex in my app matches `clients` subdomain to my `ClientsAdminPanel` plugin. You can grab that here: http://bin.cakephp.org/view/50699397 So you can see how that's done as well if you need a combination of `UserSubdomainRoute` and my `SubdomainRoute` (in the link).

Hope this helps for now. Let me know if there are any problems.

Edit:
Here's how to force a redirection - something tells me there's a better way. I'll update if I can think of it.

```
public function beforeFilter() {
     $subdomains = $this->request->subdomains();
     $subdomain = $this->Auth->user('subdomain');
     if (!empty($subdomain) && !in_array($subdomain, $subdomains)) {
        $this->redirect('http://' . $subdomain . '.site.com' . $this->request->here);
     }
}
```

Comment: This is great thanks Tigrang.

Im still not 100% though. I implemented the cakeroute override and in the _writeUrl function I am getting the correct URL with the subdomain (eg customer.example.com) but it seems ignore the returned  subdomin. The browser simply goes the the original domain. 

Its strange because if I change the subdomain to somthing fixed like 'sfdsf' this shows in the browser however this does not work when I set the subdomain from the session(I can print_r out the "{$protocol}://{$subdomain}.{$domain}{$url}"; and it looks fine.

Any ideas what is happening here?Thanks again

Comment: so doing `AuthComponent::user('subdomain')` does hold the correct value, but the browser address is still site.com without the subdomain?

Comment: Yes the session value is fine: when I output:
"{$protocol}://{$subdomain}.{$domain}{$url}" I get the exact URL that I want. BUT this is not the address that is being shown in the browser. Its really strange. By the way I upgraded to 2.1 as Im just begining my project...

Comment: You're going to have to force a redirection then if you want the address in the browser to be subdomain.site.com. What my code does is write out the full url including subdomain when you do `$this->Html->link()` calls (but will only work when url is passed as an array, not a string). So probably in beforeFilter of appcontroller check if the subdomain in session is set and then use $this->request->subdomains() and check that its in there, if not,  do a redirect to the current address and that should write out the subdomain in the address. I'm thinking of a more elegant way to do it.

Comment: Good work, many thanks. Are there any disadvantages to this method? Anyway it works ad I'm happy :)

Answer (score 0):

well if you wish to do it for all your links probably you use the same way to show all your url on your site, do you use something like $this->html->link('/blah/asd/','blah'); ?

Answer (score 0):

IN Cake/Routing/Route

```
class SubdomainRoute extends CakeRoute {
public function match($params) {
    $subdomain = isset($params['subdomain']) ? $params['subdomain'] : null;
    unset($params['subdomain']);
    $path = parent::match($params);
    if ($subdomain) {
        $path = 'http://' . $subdomain . '.localhost' . $path;
    }
    return $path;
}
}
```

When creating links you could do the following to make links pointing at other subdomains.

```
echo $this->Html->link(
    'Other domain',
     array('subdomain' => 'test', 'controller' => 'posts', 'action' => 'add')
);
```